# Can I add header on SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

I make some project in android and working with SimpleAdapter. My project work properly, but I want to customized my list view with header. Here some code from my project

**WatesActivity**

```
public class WatesActivity extends ListActivity {
static final String URL = "http://data.bmkg.go.id/propinsi_15_2.xml";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "Cuaca";
static final String KEY_ID = "Isi";
static final String KEY_ROW = "Row";
static final String KEY_KOTA = "Kota";
static final String KEY_LINTANG = "Lintang";
static final String KEY_BUJUR = "Bujur";
static final String KEY_CUACA = "Cuaca";
static final String KEY_SUHUMIN = "SuhuMin";
static final String KEY_SUHUMAX = "SuhuMax";
static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN = "KelembapanMin";
static final String KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX = "KelembapanMax";
static final String KEY_KECEPATANANGIN = "KecepatanAngin";
static final String KEY_ARAHANGIN = "ArahAngin";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kabupaten);

    new AmbilData().execute();
}

class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WatesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu Beberapa Saat...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList row_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ROW);
        int row_id = 0;
        for (int i = row_id; i < row_nodes.getLength();) {
            // org.w3c.dom.Element row_element = (org.w3c.dom.Element)
            // row_nodes.item(i);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) row_nodes.item(i);

            map.put(KEY_KOTA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KOTA));
            map.put(KEY_LINTANG, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINTANG));
            map.put(KEY_BUJUR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BUJUR));
            map.put(KEY_CUACA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CUACA));
            map.put(KEY_SUHUMIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUHUMIN));
            map.put(KEY_SUHUMAX, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUHUMAX));
            map.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN,
                    parser.getValue(e, KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN));
            map.put(KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX,
                    parser.getValue(e, KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX));
            map.put(KEY_KECEPATANANGIN,
                    parser.getValue(e, KEY_KECEPATANANGIN));
            map.put(KEY_ARAHANGIN, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARAHANGIN));

            menuItems.add(map);
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WatesActivity.this,
                        menuItems, R.layout.listkabupaten, new String[] {
                                KEY_KOTA, KEY_CUACA, KEY_LINTANG,
                                KEY_BUJUR, KEY_SUHUMIN, KEY_SUHUMAX,
                                KEY_KELEMBAPANMIN, KEY_KELEMBAPANMAX,
                                KEY_KECEPATANANGIN, KEY_ARAHANGIN },
                        new int[] { R.id.kota, R.id.cuaca, R.id.lintang,
                                R.id.bujur, R.id.suhumin, R.id.suhumax,
                                R.id.kelembapanmin, R.id.kelembapanmax,
                                R.id.kecepatanangin, R.id.arahangin });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**kabupaten.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Kota Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kota"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Linear layout for Cuaca -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Cuaca Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Cuaca : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cuaca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for Lintang -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Lintang Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Lintang : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lintang"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for Bujur -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Bujur Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Bujur : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bujur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for SuhuMin -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- SuhuMin Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="SuhuMin : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/suhumin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for SuhuMax -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- SuhuMax Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="SuhuMax : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/suhumax"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for KelembapanMin -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- KelembapanMin Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="KelembapanMin : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kelembapanmin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for KelembapanMax -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- KelembapanMax Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="KelembapanMax : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kelembapanmax"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for Kecepatan Angin -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Kecepatan Angin Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Kecepatan Angin : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kecepatanangin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Linear layout for Arah Angin -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Arah Angin Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Arah Angin : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arahangin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is add header into ListView, Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `ListView.addHeaderView(...)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html